# Linear map and Linear Independence proof

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces and $T : V → W$ is linear. If $u_1, . . . , u_n ∈ V$ and
$Tu_1, . . . , Tu_n$ are linearly independent, then $u_1, . . . , u_n$ are linearly independent.

So here is my attempt at the proof:

Assume that $Tu_1, . . . , Tu_n$ is linear independent, then $a_1Tu_1+. . .+a_nTu_n=0$, and $a_1,...,a_n=0$
Then $T(a_1u_1+...+a_nu_n)=0$
Using that fact that $T(0)=0$, $\ a_1u_1+. . .+a_nu_n=0$
So $u_1, . . . , u_n$ are linearly independent.

I have seen two solutions that they started the proof with assuming $\ a_1u_1+. . .+a_nu_n=0$, and Take T both sides by $\ T(a_1u_1+. . .+a_nu_n)=T(0)$ and prove the statement from there. Is my way correct or this is?Thanks

Comment: The second proof is the correct one. Linear independance of vectors $(u_1, .., u_n)$ *does not* mean that for $a_1 = ...= a_n=0$, one has $a_1 u_1 +... + a_n u_n = 0$ (this is always true !!). Linear independance rather means that *if* $a_1 u_1 +... + a_n u_n = 0$, *then* $a_1 = ... = a_n = 0$...

Comment: seems like I need more work regarding the last few chapters.. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $T(\mathbf u_1),\dots,T(\mathbf u_n)$ are linearly independent and let $\mathbf 0$, $\vec 0_{\mathcal V}$, $\vec 0_{\mathcal W}$ denote the additive identity of $\Bbb F$, $\mathcal V$, $\mathcal W$ respectively where $\Bbb F$ is the ground field of $\mathcal V$.

$$\forall c_1,\dots,c_n\in\Bbb F\;\;\;\sum_{i=1}^nc_i\mathbf u_i=\vec 0_{\mathcal V}\implies\sum_{i=1}^nc_iT(\mathbf u_i)=\vec 0_{\mathcal W}\implies c_1=\cdots=c_n=\mathbf 0$$